Что выведет в консоль parseInt(0.0000003)
Описание
На собеседовании задали такой вопрос:

— Что выведет в консоль parseInt(0.000003)?
"Ну, ясное дело." — 0! .
— Хорошо. А что выведет parseInt(0.0000003)?
— А какая разница? 0!

Ответ убил:

— 3!



console.log(parseInt(0.0000003));



Почему?

Для начала
Чтобы понять, как работает выражение, разберемся как работает parseInt.
Функция parseInt пытается разобрать целое число из СТРОКИ. Это ключевой момент.



Что происходит
Если передать не строковое значение как параметр, то произойдет автоматическая конвертация в строку, потом уже разбор.
Если конвертировать число 0.000003 в строку, получим "0.000003".
Если конвертировать число 0.0000003 в строку, получим... "3e-7". ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
Вот тут нюанс
По разряду слишком большие (≥ 10²¹) или слишком маленькие (≤ 10⁻⁷) числа при конвертации в строку переходят в экспоненциальный вид для более удобного чтения.


console.log(`${10 ** 20}\n${10 ** 21}`);
console.log(`${10 ** -6}\n${10 ** -7}`);



При попытке разобрать "0.000003" в целое число, берется первая группа цифр, из которой можно получить целое число - 0.
При попытке разобрать "3e-7" - 3.

стоило добавить почему в одном случае ты получаешь строку "0.000003", а в другом "3e-7"

@Grundy добавил. Не согласен с дубликатом, так как в вопросе обсуждается не только функционал parseInt

в дубликате явно расписан весь алгоритм работы parseInt - в том числе явно указано, что аргумент приводится к строке

@Grundy но оно упускает часть преобразования строки. С вопросом "Что выведет в консоль parseInt(0.0000003)" и с этим ответом я все равно бы не понял, почему выводится 3. Ну преобразуется в строку, и что это меняет? И если честно я вчера только узнал, что маленькие числа преобразуются как MeP. Так что, все ещё считаю, что не дубликат.
